# Adding classes to WP Genesis menu excluding other menu's

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class, menu

We are working with Genesis theme for WordPress and want to add some classes to the menu. We did some search online and found this code:

```
// Add a CSS class to a menu or menu item in WordPress
function modify_nav_menu_args( $args) {
        $args['menu_class'] .= ' genesis-nav-menu js-superfish sf-js-enabled sf-arrows'; 
        return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'modify_nav_menu_args' );
```

Works great only the problem is that we also have a menu in the footer and this menu is getting those classes to.

We are not using "primary" of "secondary" menu's for loading the menu's but we do it through widgets.

How can I use above function and add an if statement to it for saying that I only want to add this css to the menu with the name "main menu" and ID "11". If not "main menu", or if you want to do it by ID "11", then add other classes.

I allready found something like this:

```
function modify_nav_menu_args( $args ) {
 if( 'primary' == $args['theme_location'] ) {
 $args['menu_class'] .= ' special-class';
   }
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'modify_nav_menu_args' );
```

But then you use "primary" of the theme_location and we are not using "primary" or "secondary".

Somebody can help me out how I can do this with menu name or ID?

**Var_dump $args**

```
array(17) { ["menu"]=> object(WP_Term)#21050 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(11) ["name"]=> string(9) "main menu" ["slug"]=> string(9) "main-menu" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(11) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "nav_menu" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(28) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["meta"]=> array(0) { } } ["container"]=> string(3) "div" ["container_class"]=> string(0) "" ["container_id"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_class"]=> string(4) "menu" ["menu_id"]=> string(0) "" ["echo"]=> bool(true) ["fallback_cb"]=> string(0) "" ["before"]=> string(0) "" ["after"]=> string(0) "" ["link_before"]=> string(0) "" ["link_after"]=> string(0) "" ["items_wrap"]=> string(36) "
%3$s
" ["item_spacing"]=> string(8) "preserve" ["depth"]=> int(0) ["walker"]=> string(0) "" ["theme_location"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters) variable should have what you need already.

```
function modify_nav_menu_args( $args ) {
    if ($args['menu'] instanceof WP_Term && 'main-menu' == $args['menu']->slug) {
        $args['menu_class'] .= ' genesis-nav-menu js-superfish sf-js-enabled sf-arrows';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response. What you are saying make sense but I tried it and now nothing now class is added at all. So something is wrong with the if statement I guess. I allready tried it seperatly with only $args['menu'] and $args['menu_id'] but stil no classes added... I 100% sure the ID is 11 so what could be wrong? We are loading our menu through widgets in the header? Maybe thats why it aint working?

Comment: @user2812779 I don't think so. I left out the `return` statement in my answer, but filters must return a value. Did you include it? Have you tried dumping the contents of `$args` outside the `if` to check that the menu you want is being passed?

Comment: once again thanks for the response. I added the return in the function I made so that was not it. I did a var_dump on $args. I edited my question and added the var_dump. That seems fine to me but for some strange reason no classes are added.. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user2812779 Modified to account for passing a taxonomy as the menu. Removed the id check, I don't *think* you'll need it. If you do, add another condition using `term_taxonomy_id`.

Comment: I have never came up with this myself! Thanks a lot!